# Why can't I access my git repo when upgrading to Heroku Cedar-14?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am trying to test my app on the new Heroku Cedar-14 stack, but when running the command:

```
 git push heroku-cedar-14 master
```

I get the following error:

```
remote: !   Your account my@email.com does not have access to name.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've seen similar issues that suggest upgrading ssh certificates, which I've tried with no success. Why is it that the Heroku login works when running `git push heroku master` but not when trying to deploy the code on the new stack? How can I get this to work?

Comment: If you're using the Heroku toolbelt, you'll want to ensure you're authenticated with `heroku login`

Comment: Thanks @RichPeck - I've run heroku login before this with no issues. As mentioned I can run `git push heroku master` with no issues (other than it won't push because Cedar-10 is out of support) - it's only when trying to push to the new stack that the authentication fails.